# What are the monk's stat bonuses?

Tags: monk, bonus-type

I can't seem to find what bonuses the monk gets. I play a genasi monk, and I know that I get a +1 on Wisdom because of my race. I also know that Dexterity and Constitution are important for a monk, but what bonuses do those stats get? Are there upgrades? Or am I stuck with what I rolled?

Comment: Which game are you playing?

Comment: Also, which edition of that game? I assume D&D 5th edition, where water genasi get +1 Wisdom, but you must tag the question as such before anyone can answer it.